# How to change my phone model if i have root access?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have rooted my phone and changed the os with CM9.X.

My phone name was Sony Xperia MINI sk17i. after installing of new os then model name has been changed.

So i want to change this this to that name. I have terminal app & have root access how can i do that, Please advice me.

Comment: Which model string is currently set? And why would you want to do that? It's checked by subsequent updates to be sure the update fits. Have a look at /system/build.prop for variables starting with 'ro.product.'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**WARNING:** Messing with your `build.prop` file can have serious repercussions to your ROM. It is a very 'sensitive' file and can cause unforseen consequences. Doing any of the below is done at your own risk. ALWAYS make a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup before messing with a ROM. I learned this the hard way, don't do what I did!

---

This should work, though it depends on CM9:

Download [Root Explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/root-explorer/com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) for your phone.

1. Open root explorer, go to `/system`, and Search `Build.prop`
2. Open with text Editor
3. Search your baseband and device model
   *Don't edit anything except baseband, custom ROM and device model.*
4. Reboot
5. Look in *Settings → About*

**EDIT:** Here is an alternative method for doing the same using [ES file explorer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/es-file-explorer-file-manager/com.estrongs.android.pop). I haven't tested this myself, but it has more detail for a beginner. See [XDA Developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1948558).

**EDIT 2:** [build.prop Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nathan.jf.build.prop.editor) is an app to modify your `build.prop` directly. I have NOT tested this either so use at your own risk. Link to source code in the description in the play store.

Comment: "I learned this the hard way, don't do what I did!"  Sounds a bit scary! What did you learn? Is there a risk of bricking the phone? Otherwise can't you just keep changing the file until it works properly?

Comment: @Poldie I didn't brick it entirely, but it didn't boot until I reinstalled the ROM. I didn't have a nandroid backup either. It was a total pain, and wasted hours. ALWAYS backup! And I would read anything and everything on modifying build.prop files so you know in advance what to be wary of!

Comment: Another thing to be aware of when messing around in build.prop is that even though this name is purely cosmetic (doesn't impact functionality of the device itself,) Android uses this file to report the device's capabilities to Google Play Store.  There may have been a good reason for the ROM to change your phone's model name. Some device names will yield better results when trying to install apps from the Play Store. If you change it back you may find that some apps are listed as "not compatible" with your phone.

Answer (score 1):

For CM9: Get shell, get root, "setprop net.hostname whateveryouwant" for a temporary change to test. Will reset on reboot. To make this change permanent, you'll need to add it to build.prop. Add it as a new line "net.hostname=NewDeviceName" and you're set.

Comment: You could make this more clear I think, perhaps more of a step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Use this application. Do the same things but safe.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.model.phonemodelchanger&hl=en